# bind data to repeater inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi have a repeater which is inside a gridview. when i bind the data to gridview the data is binding to the controles inside the gridview but repeater is not binding.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMain" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          Width="200px" Height="200px" 
    onrowdatabound="gvMain_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDptName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deptName")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDptDesc" runat="server" Text = "sdfsdfsdfdsf"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rtFunctions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rtFunctions_ItemDataBound" >
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnFunctions" runat="server" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbltemp" Style="border:1px solid blue;width:20px;height:20px;background:green" runat="server" Text="TempLabel" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

in Page load:

```
gvMain.DataSource = objDeptColl;
                    gvMain.DataBind();
```

Codebehind for repeater:

```
protected void gvMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            FunctionCollection objTempFuncColl = new FunctionCollection();
            objTempFuncColl = (FunctionCollection)Cache["objFuncColl"];
            Repeater rt = (Repeater)e.Row.FindControl("rtFunctions");

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && objTempFuncColl.Count !=0 )
            {
                rt.DataSource = objTempFuncColl;
                rt.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void rtFunctions_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        FunctionCollection objTempFuncColl = new FunctionCollection();
        objTempFuncColl = (FunctionCollection)Cache["objFuncColl"];
        Repeater rt = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rtFunctions");
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            foreach (Functions f in objTempFuncColl)
            {
                LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnFunctions");
                lnk.Text = f.funcName;
            }
        }
    }
```

linkbutton in gridview is binding but the linkbutton in repeater is not binding.

Comment: where is the code to actually bind data to the repeater?

Comment: I have added the code ..please see that in the question

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the DataBind() for repeater, does it hit it?

Comment: Yes.. the foreach loop in the Itemdatabound event is iterating and the funcName value is appending to the link button but it is not displaying in the repeater.

Comment: if you add some default text to the Linkbutton and comment out the code that attempts to change it, does it display then? To be honest, comment out the whole rtFunctions_ItemDataBound and see what happens.

Comment: I thought like that once so used the label after the link button . Text for that also not displaying

Comment: Does f.funcName have a value?

Comment: Yes.. it is binding the linkbutton with the values. problem is linkbutton value is not displaying

Comment: Are you sure? If you are setting lnk.Text to ""/string.empty, you wont see it, same with the label. Put a breakpoint on f.funcName and jsut confirm. I have been caught out by silly things like this before

Comment: ChrisBint: linkbutton is assigning to the value properly. see the label in the aspx. I dont know why the label text also not displaying

Comment: @ChrisBint let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1179/discussion-between-karthik-k-and-chris-bint)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the funcName actually has a value to display? It may be assigning it, but if it is assigning it to an empty string, nothing would be displayed. Put a breakpoint on the code and hover over f.funcName and make sure it actually has a value.

Comment: It is having the values.

Comment: Do you see them (label and link) in the HTML source?

Comment: no.. trying to approach in different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with your repeater ondatabound function.

```
    FunctionCollection objTempFuncColl = new FunctionCollection();
    objTempFuncColl = (FunctionCollection)Cache["objFuncColl"];
```

The first line is not needed as you then replace it with the contents of the cache, which might be null if it's expired or purged or an instance.

For each row in your repeater, the link will be set to the last value in the objtempfunccoll.

you don't really need any of the function apart from `lnk.Text = f.funcName;` (you'll need to cast f from dataitem)

When you databind to the gridview, ondatabound is called for each row. you've got that wired-up. For each row you now need to find the repeater, set its datasource (we'll call this inner collection) & call databind on the repeater. this will cause ondatabound on the repeater to be called but the container.dataitem now points to each item in the inner collection. We can use that directly, casting container.dataitem to whatever type the inner collection is a list of.

```
protected void gvMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    FunctionCollection objTempFuncColl = (FunctionCollection)Cache["objFuncColl"];
    Repeater rt = (Repeater)e.Row.FindControl("rtFunctions");

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && objTempFuncColl.Count !=0 )
    {
        rt.DataSource = objTempFuncColl;
        rt.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void rtFunctions_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    lnk.Text = ((Functions)e.Item.DataItem).funcName;
}
```

Simon

Comment: Simon: I think the solution you gave me may work. Can you explain littile more clear?

Comment: Added a more detailed explanation

Comment: Can you post the code to add the containerdataitem to the repeater?

Comment: Added code, assuming FunctionCollection is a collection of Functions objects

Comment: Thanks for helping ...I have tried with your code. The final value is ovewrriting the previous values. i.e It is looping through each rowitem but the final row link button value is overriding the previous rows.

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be binding the repeater within any of this code. You may have some code to bind data to the GridView control, but this will not automatically bind anything to the repeater within the ItemTemplate.

Comment: in the `gvMain_RowDataBound` method there is a `DataBind` call.

Comment: There was not when the code was posted, see comments from question.

Comment: Yes chris I have aded after asked the particulars

Answer (score 0):

Why don't databind in the aspx, leaving empty the code behind:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMain" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          Width="200px" Height="200px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDptName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deptName")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDptDesc" runat="server" Text = "sdfsdfsdfdsf"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rtFunctions" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Cache["objFuncColl"] %>' >
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnFunctions" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("funcName") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbltemp" Style="border:1px solid blue;width:20px;height:20px;background:green" runat="server" Text="TempLabel" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: splitting hairs, but don't you mean DataSource='<%# Cache["objFuncColl"]

Comment: @Simon, you're right, thank you. I was deceived by my recent usage of Scala :)